# Strange behavior with jQuery's clone() and a POST request

Tags: jquery, forms, post

Playing around with jQuery, I was trying to dynamically multiply a form element (a file upload box) on the click of a button. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#new-image').click(function () {
        var idx = $('.input.file').size();
        var upload = $('.input.file:first-child').clone();
        $(upload.find('label')).attr('for', 'Attachment'+idx+'File');
        $(upload.find('input[type=file]')).attr('name', 'data[Attachment]​['+idx+']​[file]');
        $(upload.find('input[type=file]')).attr('id', 'Attachment'+idx+'File');
        upload.insertBefore('#new-image');
        return false;
    });
});
```

The problem is that, if I try and modify the input's name I end up with something like this in the post request - taken from Chrome's (dev build) console, also borks on Firefox (3.6).

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryMXYcXg2mbP1HZsVJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[Attachment]â€‹[3]â€‹[file]"; filename="logo.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

It is not because of the string concatenation, I tried with a hardcoded value and the weirdness in the request was still there. Am I missing something here or is this a bug in jQuery?

(If anyone is wondering, the name attribute format - `data[...` comes from CakePHP)

---

## Update

It seems the problem is not because of `.attr()`, but because of `.clone()`. I modified the question accordingly.

I was under the impression that this worked:

```
upload.find('input[type=file]').name = 'data[Attachment]​['+idx+']​[file]';
// wrong -> find returns a jQuery object and setting name has no effect
```

because I did not try to add multiple files, I was just trying the last added field :). It does not work even in the correct form:

```
upload.find('input[type=file]').get(0).name = 'data[Attachment]​['+idx+']​[file]';
// I still get mumbo-jumbo in the post, between the ][ characters
```

I just tried without `clone()` and it works, for real this time :).

```
$('#new-image').click(function () {
    var idx = $('.input.file').size();
    var upload = $('<div class="input file"><label for="Attachment'+idx+'File">File</label><input type="file" name="data[Attachment]['+idx+'][file]" id="Attachment'+idx+'File"></div>');
    upload.insertBefore('#new-image');
    return false;
});
```

Does anyone have any idea why `clone()` behaves this way?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `var idx = $('.input.file').length;`?

Comment: `size()` also works: http://api.jquery.com/size/. I should switch to `length`, but this is more of an experiment than something that will hit production so I didn't pay that much attention :).

Comment: Tried to reproduce and failed: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/tKp4z/ can you update the code there and reproduce what you describe?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/DJ6Ep/. The weird characters are _not_ visible when you clone the element, only in the body of the post request.

Comment: @Alex I'll have to test it tomorrow, don't have server at my disposal ATM :/

Comment: Ok, no problem :). Maybe I'll figure it out by then, I'll post here. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Works here on Chrome stable (10.0.648.151).

Comment: Works for me on Chrome dev (11.0.696.14). Also, you're needlessly double-wrapping your find() result; that will already give you a jQuery object back, so there's no need to $(x.find('')).  Also, for what it's worth, the nested bracket object notation is standard-by-convention to x-www-form-urlencoded. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="file">
    <div>
        <label for="Attachment0File">File: </label>
        <input type="file" name="data[Attachment][file][]" id="Attachment0File" />
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="new-image">New</button>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#new-image').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var idx = $('.file').length;
        $('.file:first-child').clone(true, true)
            .find('label').attr('for', 'Attachment'+idx+'File').end()
            .find('input[type="file"]').attr('name', 'data[Attachment][file][]').attr('id', 'Attachment'+idx+'File').end()
            .insertBefore('#new-image');
    });
});
```

upload does not need to be wrapped with $() since it is already a jQuery objct